# JS onclick select partial text in input - start from cursor position to the end of string (afterCaret)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, getcaretpos

I need tricky function, when I OnClick on the input field it will select text from cursor position (afterCaret) to the end of text value.

```
<input> I am input example textfield text </input>
```

When I will put cursor by clicking by mouse.. let's say in the middle of word "exa | mple", output should be highlighted text: "**mple textfield text**"

(after that I will press Delete :) but I dont wanna delete it automatically by function, only select)

I found this, perfect example, but I'm not able to use it right with my knowledge :(
http://javascript.nwbox.com/cursor_position/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
<input id="text" type="text" value="EXAMPLE" size="20" />
```

JavaScript Version:

```
document.getElementById('text').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var length = this.value.length;
    this.setSelectionRange(this.selectionStart, length);
},
false);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z9tqy47j/)

JQuery Version:

```
$('#text').on('click', function() {
    var length = $(this).val().length;
    this.setSelectionRange(this.selectionStart, length);
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qfg2fovb/)

Comment: wow :) you rock! hope it helps also to others, coz I didn't find answer to this in here :)

Comment: might be better to be doing this call on "focus" no?

Comment: @PimBrouwers - Your suggestion appears to have no effect. When you click on the input, both events are fired, but the `click` event fires after the `focus` event. When you tab to an input, only `focus` is fired, but the normal behavior is that the entire text is selected. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qfg2fovb/1/)